# AutoMapper's ForMember with property name parameter VS ForMember with Expression parameter, Performance?

Tags: c#, automapper, performance-testing

In AutoMapper we can use `ForMember` method in config with the following signatures:

```
IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> ForMember(Expression<Func<TDestination, object>> destinationMember, Action<IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource>> memberOptions);
IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> ForMember(string name, Action<IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource>> memberOptions);
```

I manually tested them, `ForMember` with expression parameter had better performance.
Witch one is recommended for better performance?

Comment: Whichever one performs better in the tests. :)

Comment: It's not a choice driven by performance (unless the differences are considerable, which I can't imagine). Always use strong-typed code if possible. No-brainer in this case.